# Sumar Valores contenidos en un Array PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo la siguiente inquietud. Teniendo estos arrays:

```
$array1 = array(1,1,3,2,6,4,6,4);
$array2 = array(1,2,0,1,3,5,1,5);
$array3 = array(0,4,1,1,1,2,1,2);
```

Necesito sumar los valores contenidos en ellos pero no su acumulativo, sino de manera individual (el valor de cada índice) y crear un nuevo array con la suma de los mismos, por ejemplo:

```
SALIDA:
$array_suma = array(2,7,4,4,10,11,8,11); (cada valor es la suma del valor de cada indice de cada array).
```

Alguien me pude orientar a como solucionar este problema? Saludos y gracias por su ayuda e informacion.

Comment: 1. contadores `$contadores=[count($array1), count($array2), count($array3)];` 2. máxima longitud `$max = max($contadores)` 3. iteras sumando `$salida = []; for($i=0; $i<max; $i++){ $a1 = isset(array1[$i])?array1[$i]:0;  $a2 = isset(array2[$i])?array1[$i]:0;  $a3 = isset(array3[$i])?array1[$i]:0; $salida[$i] = $a1+$a2+$a3; }` 4. devuelves el array $salida. **observa el uso de operadores ternarios** para asignar cero si el item no existe en caso de arrays de longitudes diferentes

Comment: @quevedo si es la respuesta, entonces agrega una, por otro lado, pienso que esto es un ejercicio y aunque no lo fuera, de igual forma se deberia mostrar lo que se intento y no resolverlo

Comment: @JuanRivera Solo le ilustré el uso de ciclos de control y operador condicional ternario. Que es casi la solución de ejercicio, es cierto. Por eso no lo puse como respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

hice el siguiente ejercicio y me funcionó a la perfección:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(1,1,3,2,6,4,6,4);
$array2 = array(1,2,0,1,3,5,1,5);
$array3 = array(0,4,1,1,1,2,1,2);

$size = count($array1);

for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $suma = ($array1[$i] + $array2[$i] + $array3[$i]);
    $resultado []= $suma;
}

print_r($resultado);
?>
```

Si quieres obtener la suma de una columna específica lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:
(Recuerda que en programación se empieza a contar desde el cero.)

```
print_r($resultado[2]); // Columna 2 = (3 + 0 + 1)
// Resultado: 4
```

Cualquier duda dejamelo saber en los comentarios, espero te sirva :D